# Consulta sobre mostrar una lista

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

estoy tratando de poblar un `RecyclerView` con todas las `Apps` instaladas en un dispositivo. Para ello, he creado una clase:

```
public class Paquetes {
    private String nombreApp;
    private String paqueteApp;

    public String getNombreApp() {
        return nombreApp;
    }

    public void setNombreApp(String nombreApp) {
        this.nombreApp = nombreApp;
    }

    public String getPaqueteApp() {
        return paqueteApp;
    }

    public void setPaqueteApp(String paqueteApp) {
        this.paqueteApp = paqueteApp;
    }

    public Paquetes() {
    }

    public Paquetes(String nombreApp, String paqueteApp) {
        this.nombreApp = nombreApp;
        this.paqueteApp = paqueteApp;
    }
}
```

Luego, he creado el adaptador en el cual intento obtener el nombre de los paquetes:

```
public class AdaptadorRecyclerView extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdaptadorRecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private final ArrayList<Paquetes> paquetesArrayList;

    public AdaptadorRecyclerView(ArrayList<Paquetes> paquetesArrayList, Context context){
        this.paquetesArrayList = paquetesArrayList;

        final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        paquetesArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        List<ResolveInfo> todasLasApps = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(i, 0);
        for(ResolveInfo rI : todasLasApps){
            Paquetes paquetes = new Paquetes(rI.loadLabel(packageManager).toString(), rI.activityInfo.packageName + " / " + rI.activityInfo.loadIcon(packageManager));
            paquetesArrayList.add(paquetes);
        }

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public AdaptadorRecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.diseno_lista, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdaptadorRecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position){
        String appLabel = paquetesArrayList.get(position).getNombreApp();
        String appPackage = paquetesArrayList.get(position).getPaqueteApp();
        holder.nombreApp.setText(appLabel);
        holder.paqueteApp.setText(appPackage);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){
        return paquetesArrayList.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        TextView nombreApp, paqueteApp;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View view){
            super(view);
            nombreApp = view.findViewById(R.id.nombreAppTextView);
            paqueteApp = view.findViewById(R.id.paqueteAppTextView);
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            int itemPosition = getAbsoluteAdapterPosition();
        }
    }
}
```

Y mi activity ha quedado así:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private AdaptadorRecyclerView adaptadorRecyclerView;
    private ArrayList<Paquetes> paquetesArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewPantallaPrincipal);

        try {
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
            adaptadorRecyclerView = new AdaptadorRecyclerView(paquetesArrayList, MainActivity.this);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adaptadorRecyclerView);
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("BANNER", "onCreate: " + e.getMessage());
        }


    }

    private void bannerPrincipal(){
        MobileAds.initialize(MainActivity.this, initializationStatus -> {});
        AdView adView = findViewById(R.id.bannerPantallaPrincipal);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
}
```

Pero, al iniciar la aplicación no me muestra nada y el `LogCat` no muestra errores. ¿En qué estoy errándole?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El único problema que puedo ver es que creas una lista pero no esta inicializada, `paquetesArrayList` no tiene valores, debes llenar este listado con los paquetes de aplicaciones al instanciar `AdaptadorRecyclerView` :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     ... 
     private ArrayList<Paquetes> paquetesArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            ...
            ...
            ...
            adaptadorRecyclerView = new AdaptadorRecyclerView(paquetesArrayList, MainActivity.this);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adaptadorRecyclerView);
            ...
            ...

    }
```

Comment: No puedo creer que no me haya dado cuenta de eso, mil gracias genio!